# Spring Security stateless OAuth2 Authorization Code Grant flow

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2

For my Spring Boot 2.4 application, I've configured OAuth2 Login (OpenID Connect) that uses the OAuth 2.0 Authorization Code Grant flow internally.

The OAuth 2.0 specification for this flow defines the `state` parameter as recommended, mostly for CSRF-protection issues. A sample request looks like the following:

```
https://authorization-server.com/oauth/authorize
?client_id=a17c21ed
&response_type=code
&state=5ca75bd30
&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fexample-app.com%2Fauth
&scope=photos
```

As the application should run with multiple instances (at least two), I'm running into issues as this `state` parameter is randomly generated with different values for each Spring Boot instance. So the callback has to arrive at the same instance the request was initiated, as otherwise, the validation of this `state` field fails.

The relevant Spring Security code part I found is the following (`resolve` method of `DefaultOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver`)

```
builder.clientId(clientRegistration.getClientId())
                .authorizationUri(clientRegistration.getProviderDetails().getAuthorizationUri())
                .redirectUri(redirectUriStr)
                .scopes(clientRegistration.getScopes())
                .state(this.stateGenerator.generateKey()) // this line generates it
                .attributes(attributes);
```

If I enable sticky sessions on the load balancer, everything works as expected. But then I wouldn't describe the application setup as fully *stateless*.

Is there are way to persist the used `state` parameter e.g. in a database to share it among several Spring Boot instances to verify the callback at every instance? Or do I have to manually provide a custom `StringKeyGenerator` and somehow tweak the `state` validation?

Answer (score 2):

i looked a bit into it and as you say, it seems like it is non configurable, and your demand is definitely not unreasonable.

I think this is worthy of an issue to be opened at [Spring Security Github Issues](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues) The [stategenerator](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/848bd448374156020210c329b886fca010a5f710/oauth2/oauth2-client/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/web/DefaultOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver.java#L77) should at least be an interface with a default implementation that you can override, because the state generator is not only used as a form of CSRF, it should also be useable to send any form of custom stateful parameter if needed.

Im afraid that as of now the workaround you have is to extend the default `DefaultOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver` and override the [`DefaultOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver#Resolve`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/848bd448374156020210c329b886fca010a5f710/oauth2/oauth2-client/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/web/DefaultOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver.java#L141) function and copy over the default implementation.

Or implement a custom `OAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver` using the interface [`OAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/web/OAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver.html) and copy over the relevant code from the default one.

And when you have a default implementation you can customise i would implement a shared in memory cache between the services, for instance Hazelcast or a Redis, with a short eviction time so you don't have to deal with databases.

But i do think you should open an issue for them to add the customisation.

I also found [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-custom-oauth-requests) link that customises some things.

Comment: thanks a lot for your investigation and for confirming that this is not unreasonable. I was also _afraid_ that there is not an easy solution for this. Somehow there are points for extendedility, but I'll reach out to the Spring Security team.

Comment: there is one related issue which is unfortunately closed https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/7808